# Datatable items not showing in Crystal Report

Tags: vb.net, crystal-reports

So I have a project in vs2010 and tried to use Crystal Report to print a receipt. I have this listview where all the items being purchased are displayed and those items will be send to the Cyrstal Report via DataSet's DataTable but it wont show. Please someone tell me what is wrong with my code.

rpt design

[image]

rpt Output not showing the list from listview

[image]

```
    Private Sub orForm_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        Dim myOR As New salesReceipt
        Dim cashier As TextObject = myOR.ReportDefinition.ReportObjects("Text11")
        Dim dtm As TextObject = myOR.ReportDefinition.ReportObjects("Text12")

        Dim ds As New DataSet
        Dim dt As New DataTable
        ds.Tables.Add(dt)
        With dt
            .Columns.Add("Items")
            .Columns.Add("Quantity")
            .Columns.Add("Total")
        End With
        For i As Integer = 0 To main.lvItemsToPurchase.Items.Count - 1
            Dim dr As DataRow = dt.NewRow
            dr("Items") = main.lvItemsToPurchase.Items.Item(i).SubItems(1).Text
            dr("Quantity") = main.lvItemsToPurchase.Items.Item(i).SubItems(3).Text
            dr("Total") = main.lvItemsToPurchase.Items.Item(i).SubItems(5).Text
            dt.Rows.Add(dr)
        Next

        cashier.Text = "Cashier: " & curUser
        dtm.Text = "Date/Time: " & Format(Now, "MMMM dd, yyyy") & " " & FormatDateTime(Now, DateFormat.LongTime)
        myOR.SetDataSource(ds)
        CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = myOR
    End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `myOR.SetDataSource(ds.Tables(0))`, A dataset contains more than one datatable so you should specify the datatable in a dataset

Comment: I have tried your solution but its still not showing the content of my datatable index 0 or perhaps  I have to bind the three text fields in section(3) from my Crystal Report to my Datatable's columns? but I don't know how to do it.

Comment: have a look at this - http://vb.net-informations.com/crystal-report/vb.net_crystal_report_without_database.htm and https://www.codeproject.com/tips/754037/bind-crystal-reports-with-dataset-or-datatable

Comment: your first solution, i don't get it to work but the link you give just did the magic, thanks